# Auto delete older files after numbers of file reaches to 100

Tags: python, csv

I am creating CSV file from incoming data

```
import csv
data = ["value %d" % i for i in range(1,4)]

    for i in range(100):
        out = csv.writer(open(i+"myfile.csv","w"), delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        out.writerow(data)
```

After 100 files gets created, I want to del older files. How to auto del older file?

Comment: What filetime are you using for each of the files?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
import glob
import os
if i == 100:
    for f in glob.glob("path_to_folder"):
        os.remove(f)
```

or To remove the whole directory, you can try:

```
import shutil
if i == 100:
    shutil.rmtree("path_to_folder")
```